# Zend Form and jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, zend-framework2

Having following registration form

```
<?php 
    $form = $this->form;
    if(isset($form)) $form->prepare();
    $form->setAttribute('action', $this->url(NULL,
    array('controller' => 'register', 'action' => 'process')));
    $form->setAttribute('method', 'post');
    echo $this->form()->openTag($form);
?>
<dl class="form-signin">
    <dd><?php
        echo $this->formElement($form->get('name_reg'));
        echo $this->formElementErrors($form->get('name_reg'));
?></dd>

<div class="alert alert-danger alert-block fade in" id="emailCheck">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
    <p>Invalid email format</p>
</div><!-- end alert -->
<dd><?php
    echo $this->formElement($form->get('email_reg'));
    echo $this->formElementErrors($form->get('email_reg'));
?></dd>

<div class="alert alert-danger alert-block fade in" id="passwordCheck">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
    <p></p>
</div><!-- end alert -->
<dd><?php
    echo $this->formElement($form->get('password_reg'));
    echo $this->formElementErrors($form->get('password_reg'));
?></dd>

<dd><?php
    echo $this->formElement($form->get('confirm_password_reg'));
    echo $this->formElementErrors($form->get('confirm_password_reg'));
?></dd>
<br>
<dd><?php
    echo $this->formElement($form->get('send_reg'));
    echo $this->formElementErrors($form->get('send_reg'));
?></dd>

<?php echo $this->form()->closeTag() ?>
```

Added jQuery library and script.js in register's layout using:

```
<?php echo $this->headScript()
    ->prependFile($this->basePath() . '/js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js')
      ->prependFile($this->basePath() . '/js/script.js')
; ?>
```

Structure of script.js:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#btnRegister").click( function() {
        $("#email").css("border-color", "");
        $("#password").css("border-color", "");

        var email = $("#email").val();
        var password = $("#password").val();
        var confirm_password = $("#confirm_password").val();
        $("#Register").submit( function() {
           return false;    
        });
        if((/([\w\-]+\@[\w\-]+\.[\w\-]+)/.test(email)) != true) {
            $("#email").css("border-color", "red");
            $("#emailCheck").slideDown();
        } else if(password.length < 6) {
            $("#password").css("border-color", "red");
            $("#passwordCheck").text("Password must be at least 6 characters long");
            $("#passwordCheck").slideDown();
        } else if ((password == confirm_password) != true) {
            $("#password").css("border-color", "red");
            $("#passwordCheck").text("Password doesn't match");
            $("#passwordCheck").slideDown();
        } else if((/((?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[A-Z]))/gm.test(password)) != true) {
            $("#password").css("border-color", "red");
            $("#passwordCheck").text("Password must contian at least one digit and upper case");
            $("#passwordCheck").slideDown();
        }   else  { 
         $.post( $("#Register").attr("action"),
                 $("#Register :input").serializeArray(),
                 function(info) {
                   clear();
                 });
         location.href = "auth";
      } 
    });
    function clear() {
        $("#Register :input").each( function() {
              $(this).val("");
        });
    }
});
```

***Problem***:

Following script is supposed by clicking button with id #btnRegister which is 'send_reg' element to not submit standart form with id #Register and do following:

1. Check for email format and in case it's incorrect to make border-color of input email red and slide down div with id #emailCheck.
2. Check for password to be at least 6 characters long and to containt at least 1 Digit and 1 Uppercase. Also check is password and cofirm_password are the same. In contrary make red border-color of Password and slide down div with id #passwordCheck with coresponding text.

I tried all this in simple php project and it worked, but then i included all this in Zend Framework and i doesn't work. Any ideas how can i check if register view gets its hand on file or how another way to include a .js file. Because when i Inspect web page in Chrome in head there is script.js.

**Fixed**
Changed

```
->prependFile($this->basePath() . '/js/script.js')
```

to

```
->appendFile($this->basePath() . '/js/script.js')
```

Comment: What do your PHP logs tell you? Can you post the errors in the logs? Do you get any error in your java script console?

Comment: I am using xampp, you mean this file "\xampp\apache\logs\error.log"?

Comment: From Console i get this error: 
**Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined **

Comment: The \xampp\apache\logs\error.log file will probably give you apache errors as well as PHP error which might muddle the waters a bit. Look in your php.ini file to configure your error file. See: http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/php-howto-turn-on-error-log-file.html

Comment: PHP puts all error to 
error_log =  "C:\xampp\php\logs\php_error_log"
and "display_errors" is on from php.ini but i don't have any error for today, that will have something simillar to my project. Found a error in java script console and that's all.

Comment: Your $ reference error may be due to you not including the main jquery file.

Comment: Well it shows that i included it, how can i include url version of jquery using headScript() ?

Comment: Are you saying that jquery and your script appear in the html head, but "$ is not defined"? Are they 404?

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/w39kh73qt59w0na/1.JPG and https://www.dropbox.com/s/3awi96eu6qzpwxx/2.JPG are showing that they are included.

Comment: My bad, all this worked when i used 
->appendFile($this->basePath() . '/js/script.js') instead of 
->prependFile($this->basePath() . '/js/script.js') 
Thus, first loaded script.js then Jquery. Problem Solved :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include `script.js` after jQuery. At the moment you're including it before, hence the error.

The simplest (and most logical) fix would be to switch to `appendFile()` instead of prependFile()`:

```
echo $this->headScript()
          ->appendFile($this->basePath() . '/js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js')
          ->appendFile($this->basePath() . '/js/script.js');
```

Comment: figured out a little befour you answered, but thanks anyway. Just Switched appendFile for script.js. And works perfect.

Comment: anyway on this case you can use InlineScript